# mosquitto MQ still sends retained messages even after clean_session set to true

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

The clean_session in the mosquito MQ has already set to true.However, when a device gets back online after it got disconnected, it still receives many retained messages which overwhelms the device.

Can any one suggest if there is any other setting we should take care of?

Answer (score 1):

A retained message are different from messages queued for a client for a persistent session.

A last retained message for a given topic will always be delivered to a client that subscribes to that topic when they (re)connect. This is not related to the clean_session flag.

The clean_session flag controls if sessions are persisted across reconnections of the same client id. If the flag is set to false subscriptions are re-established when the client reconnects and any messages published while it was offline are delivered.

If your client is getting overwhelmed by retained messages you must be subscribed to a large number of topics.